# Image to Cursor / Custom Cursor

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on a WPF Application. We created a custom component using WPF Custom Control Library project. In this, when we drag and drop, the mouse cursor should change, based on the selected component. I can create a PNG Image based on selected component, however, I am not sure how to set that image as mouse cursor. I do not want to use the WinAPI to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

The [Cursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Input.Cursor.aspx) class has a constructor that takes a stream (containing a cur or ani format) and a filename. You can convert an image to a cur file using code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1409373/802203) SO answer.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for reply, but my case without use "user32.dll". and must use only dotnet function.

Comment: Do you have a reason as to why you wish to avoid WinAPI? I would suggest ImageMagick next (which supports cur files, but that'd use P/Invoke too).

Comment: Sure, Actually we implement in POC Project, WinAPI is "Unmanaged Code" right? and when clear GC or when application close error through, and we need solution with Managed Code 

Thanks

Comment: A large portion of the .NET framework itself relies on P/Invoke to accomplish many tasks. Invoking methods on unmanaged DLLs is not inherently a bad practice and is very easy to do with .NET marshaling. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Thanks for you reply... i'll check and let you know